# Should comparison be implemented under `compare` or `operator ==` when both are needed?

Tags: c++, conventions, code-organization

In making a class, the `compare` method and the `operator==` overload should have identical functionality. Therefore, only one implementation is needed, and I'm trying to figure out if there's any reason why it should be defined in the `compare` method *rather* than the `operator==` overload.

Here's the structure defining comparison in `compare`:

```
class T {
// definition of field f
...
   bool compare(const T& t) const {
      if (this->f == t.f) { return true; }
      return false;
   }

   friend bool operator == (const T& lhs, const T& rhs) { return lhs.compare(rhs); }
}
```

versus in the `operator ==` overloading:

```
class T {
// definition of field f
...
   bool compare(const T& t) const { return *this == t; }

   friend bool operator == (const T& lhs, const T& rhs) {
      if (lhs.f == t.f) { return true; }
      return false;
   }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need a `compare` method?  `operator==` is idiomatic.

Comment: If both end up implementing the same thing with just one calling the other, then I don't see any reason to implement the functionally in one or the other. It'll be the same anyway. So who cares?

Comment: Furthermore, I'd expect compare to compare to zero (meaning, result < 0 meaning <, result == 0 meaning ==, result > 0 meaning >).

Comment: fwiw compare that return < = > 0 is now under `opeator <=>`

Comment: If these methods are really the same, then the recommendation would be simply "choose one, stick to it". If `compare` would be the expected in C++ implementation (i.e. three way comparison), then it makes sense to implement `operator ==` with `return compare(other) == 0;` rather than other way round.

Comment: Not sure who told you to implement a Method called compare, but that sounds like some advice carried over from Java or c# to me.

Answer (score 0):

## TL;DR use second variant with 'virtual' keyword, but it will be better to get rid of this bullshit at all and use operator== only

You should use method compare() only if you have other variant of objects comparison, otherwise it does not make any sense. The reason for this is implementation of std::map, std::set, sorting alghoritms, etc., which use operator==, so if you use first variation of == implementation it will be, basicaly, your operator==, but with other name, which does not make any sense.
If you still want to do it,

-You can use first variant(where == uses compare), but make compare method virtual. In this case you will be able to overload comparison method just like in Java and it will affect on comparison, but still you can do it just by creating operator== for children class, so it still doesn't make any sense

...or you can use second one, but still using 'virtual' keyword to change implementation of parent class in children classes and if you don't like == implementation you can use compare method

Not very relatable example, but I think it might help you. In OpenCV library assignment operator= for class Mat(this class contains literally array of pixels and nothing more) don't actually copies array, but copies only a pointer on array of pixels(because it's heavy operation and it doesn't required in many cases), and for actual copying method clone() used. I think you can use the same solution for your code